# Is this expected Entity Framework 7 / Core behaviour or a bug?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a simple model for the purposes of this post.

Two entities Role and Person.

```
public class Role : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> PeopleWithThisRole { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Guid? RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

If I get the Roles from the EF context, then the PeopleWithThisRole collection is empty (unless I `.Include` them. As expected.

However if I get the Roles and I then get the People as below

```
  var roles = _context.Roles.ToList();
  var people = _context.People.ToList();
```

Then `roles.PeopleWithThisRole` collection is fully populated with the people without having to `.Include` it.

Is this the expected behaviour or should I raise this as a bug?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

With many thanks to @hvd below, I have decided to keep the entities clean and not use [JsonIgnore] attribute and instead map to DTOS (which exclude those properties I don't need in the JSON) - which is probably the correct way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected and also how earlier versions of EF worked.

Your `_context` keeps track of entities loaded inside that context, to allow for saving changes. Inside that context, `Person` objects have been loaded (at your request) and their `RoleId` values are known. Inside that same context, `Role` objects with those same `Id` values have been loaded (also at your request). EF links the objects in memory based on those IDs. If you trace the SQL queries sent to the server, you should find that no queries have been sent other than those that you requested.

Comment: Thanks I get that now. I have checked the SQL and you are correct, it is not joining. The problem comes when I am returning this as JSON from a Web API, where I am returning more data than I require. I could map to DTOs or clear the collection before returning, but it seems you have little control over this :-(

Comment: @MarkChidlow You may wish to simply exclude the properties from serialisation. How to do that depends on your serialiser, but in JSON.NET, just add the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute. (If you sometimes do want to serialise the property, then it's still possible, but it get a lot more tricky.)

Comment: Thanks @hvd - you've been extremely helpful.